# How to count unknown number of floats in a string

Tags: c, string, count, floating-point, scanf

Is there any way to use `sscanf()` to count number of floating point numbers in a string?

```
count = sscanf(string, " %f %f /* an so on.. */", &temp, %temp2 /* ..*/);
```

I can put large number of `"%f"` and variables but is seems to be stupid idea, is there any way to make it flexible?
Could you help me?

EDIT: I was trying to use `strtok()` in this way but it doesn't work

```
    substring = strtok(lines_content, " " );
    temp  = sscanf(substring, "%f", &value);

    if(temp == 1)
    {
        no_of_floats_in_line++;
    }
    fflush(stdin);

    while(token = strtok(NULL, " ") != NULL)
    {
        substring = strtok(NULL, " ");
        temp  = sscanf(substring, "%f", &value);
        fflush(stdin);

        if(temp == 1)
        {
            no_of_floats_in_line++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use a loop with `strtok()` to isolate each float substring.

Comment: "doesn't work" - please be specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `strtok()` to isolate each float in a string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {
    char flotsam[] = "0.0 1.1 2.2 PI 4.4";
    char *tok;
    float jetsam;
    int count = 0;
    tok = strtok(flotsam, " \f\r\n\t\v");
    while (tok) {
        if (sscanf(tok, "%f", &jetsam) == 1) {
            count++;
            printf ("Float is %f\n", jetsam);
        }
        else
            printf ("Error with %s\n", tok);
        tok = strtok(NULL, " \f\r\n\t\v");
    }
    printf ("Found %d floats\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
Float is 0.000000
Float is 1.100000
Float is 2.200000
Error with PI
Float is 4.400000
Found 4 floats
```

Comment: Note: rather than use only 4 of the 6 standard `isspace()` white spaces, suggest `" \f\n\r\t\v"`.

Comment: `printf ("Error with %s\n", jetsam);` is a problem.

Comment: @chux thanks for the catch - edited. Lazy of me not to include a non-float in the string.